# file include not working in case of query failure in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am including a php file in when a mysql query is failed. That included file is not working. Following is the snippet which is not working. Please check.

```
$countsql2='SELECT * from table_name';

$countsql3 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $countsql2) or die("
  <div id='fail_container'>
    <div id='fail_grid'>
      <span class='searched_invalid'>There seems to be an issue with the server connectivity.Please Try again later.</span><br />
      <span class='searched_invalid'>We have an option to check out the categories here</span>  
    </div>
  </div>"
include 'file1.php');
```

I want to show included php file when query is failed. But when I remove the include part in die part, it runs fine. But I want to run it with include php file.

Please help me in correcting this or if it can be done in some other way.

Comment: `die` function accept only one parameter which is a string and it will output the same. You can't pass include function to it.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because [die](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php) stops your application.

What you could do is:

```
if ( !$countsql3 = mysqli_query( $mysqli, $countsql2 ) )
{
    echo "<div id='fail_container'>
        <div id='fail_grid'>
            <span class='searched_invalid'>There seems to be an issue with the server connectivity.Please Try again later.</span><br />
            <span class='searched_invalid'>We have an option to check out the categories here</span>    
        </div>
    </div>";

    include('file1.php');

    die;
}
```

Comment: still that file1.php is not getting displayed sir.

Comment: @micheal Are you getting any errors? Also did you check that your file path is correct?

Comment: ya.i did check file path is correct.not displaying any error

Comment: Try to enable higher error reporting: 
`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in `if` statement, like this:

```
$countsql2='SELECT * from table_name';

$countsql3 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $countsql2);

if (!$countsql3) {
    echo "<div id='fail_container'>
        <div id='fail_grid'>
        <span class='searched_invalid'>There seems to be an issue with the server connectivity.Please Try again later.</span><br />
        <span class='searched_invalid'>We have an option to check out the categories here</span>    
        </div>
    </div>"

    include 'file1.php';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: isnt there should be colon before include line

Comment: still that file1.php is not getting displayed sir.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this full path of...

> file1.php

If file1.php still doesn't show, you could try to get root folder with `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];` and add your current location.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$countsql2='SELECT * from table_name';
if ( !$countsql3 = mysqli_query( $mysqli, $countsql2 ) )
{
    echo "<div id='fail_container'>
        <div id='fail_grid'>
            <span class='searched_invalid'>There seems to be an issue with the server connectivity.Please Try again later.</span><br />
            <span class='searched_invalid'>We have an option to check out the categories here</span>    
        </div>
    </div>";

    require('/full/path/to/file/file1.php');
}
```